# Meaningful markup of a Domain Object in a Webapp

Tags: html, xhtml, semantic-web

I'm looking to represent some domain model objects in a web app I'm writing and I'm looking for best-practices for markup.

For example in yaml:

```
--- !ruby/object:User 
email: jd@example.org
first: John
last: Doe
login: jdoe
member_since: 2009-01-22 00:54:08.128094 -05:00
```

What would be a sensible way to present this? Or the best practice for marking up this data.

Edit: All i care about right now is structure, I'll apply style when it becomes required.

Comment: by markup do you mean how to display it?

Comment: No, I mean what tags should I use to best represent my data, style can be applied later. So far I've tried some prose inside a <p> but it isn't very well structured.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda of an open-ended question, but I'll suggest a direction to get the conversation going.

Since your example uses a User object, I'll recommend that you check out the structure that is used by the [hCard microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard). [A nice example](http://rhizohm.net/contact.html) of the microformat in action.

The super cool people at Mix Online created a [bunch of CSS options](http://www.visitmix.com/Lab/oomph) in their Oomph toolkit to show how versatile the microformat is when it does come time to stylize your data.

That being said, microformats aren't really the important part here, it is the way the microformat structure lets you convert raw data into a markup structure that is machine-legible but still easy to stylize.